# Private iTunes file sharing iOS

Tags: ios, file, save, itunes, private

I can share my files by iTunes file sharing and they are stored in document directory.

1) I want to do it in such a way that user cannot take out those file unless it is allowed by app. Is it possible to do?

2) How can I create folder in the iTunes file sharing?

3) If no.1 can't be done, what are the possible method to store file with about 100MB file size securely?

Comment: So you want to pirate someone else's video but you don't want anyone to pirate your already pirated video? Pretty cool.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It is about programming.Sunny shah answered how to create file in document directory.

Comment: Actually it's a good question and programming related so I vote up. I want to implement some similar feature like this. For example, I want to only show files with particular extension to be shown in iTunes. Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add `(.)` before file name it will be hidden not available to others